# Pascal Script fails to retrieve wide string from a custom DLL

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I need Inno Setup to load a wide string from a function in a custom DLL. I have no problem loading Ansi strings – this, for example, works fine:

```cpp
int __stdcall GetStringA(char *lpText)
{
    StringCchCopyA(lpText, 30, "New Ansi value");
    return strlen(lpText);
}
```

**Pascal Script**

```pascal
function GetStringA(lpText: AnsiString): Integer;
  external 'GetStringA@files:MyDll.dll';

function LoadStringA(): AnsiString;
var
  Str: AnsiString;
  Length: Integer;
begin
  Str := 'Initial Ansi value';
  SetLength(Str, 30);
  Length := GetStringA(Str);
  SetLength(Str, Length);
  Result := Str; // Str == 'New Ansi value'
end;
```

Doing the same thing with wide strings fails, however:

```cpp
int __stdcall GetStringW(wchar_t *lpText)
{
    StringCchCopyW(lpText, 30, L"New Wide value");
    return wcslen(lpText);
}
```

**Pascal Script**

```pascal
function GetStringW(lpText: WideString): Integer;
  external 'GetStringW@files:MyDll.dll';

function LoadStringW(): WideString;
var
  Str: WideString;
  Length: Integer;
begin
  Str := 'Initial Wide value';
  SetLength(Str, 30);
  Length := GetStringW(Str); // ** DOES NOT ALTER 'Str' **
  SetLength(Str, Length);
  Result := Str; // Str == 'Initial Wide v' (old string, new length)
end;
```

Sending a `WideString` **to** the DLL works fine. Changing the buffer contents in the DLL also works fine…but somehow that does not percolate back to my Pascal Script variable.

I *suspect* that some sort of marshaling goes on under the hood, so that the DLL actually manipulates a copy of my variable. Any insights or workarounds appreciated!

I'm using Inno Setup 6.2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work by replacing `WideString` with `String`:

```pascal
function GetStringW(lpText: String): Integer;
  external 'GetStringW@files:MyDll.dll';

function LoadStringW(): WideString;
var
  Str: String;
  Length: Integer;
begin
  Str := 'Initial Wide value';
  SetLength(Str, 30);
  Length := GetStringW(Str); // ** ALTERS 'Str' **
  SetLength(Str, Length);
  Result := Str; // Str == 'New Wide value'
end;
```

I'd have thought `WideString` and `String` were equivalent, but apparently not quite. It is necessary to change both the function prototype and the `Str` declaration. It is not necessary to change the `LoadStringW` return type, though you may – and the returned value can in either case be assigned to a variable of type `WideString` or `String` without problem.

So: Problem solved. I'm still curious about the underlying behavior, though.